# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'format' : Crontab error

Tags: python, cron

I have a cronjob set that runs 00:00 GMT everyday.This cronjob executes a shell script which calls a python script internally.The python script generates a log file as output.The shell script and python script are located in the same directory in the unix box(/abc/logs/env/pqr/hvi/). They have 777 as permission.Now, when i run the shell script from this location(/abc/logs/env/pqr/hvi/) it executes fine and the python script internally gets called & generates the log file.But when this is executed through the cronjob , the output file is not generated and I get a error message saying **"AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'format' "**
When I do a **which python** I get : somelocation/../thirdparty/python/2.6/bin/python
So I think I am using python 2.6 which supports **.format** operation.
My guesses here are:

1. Python interpreter issue for which I added below to cronjob:

   PYTHONPATH =/../../../thirdparty/python/2.6/bin/python
   PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

But no luck

2. Python version issue as it might not be supporting '.format' function of datetime. But I guess I am using Python2.6 ( which python shows 2.6) & it supports this function of datetime.

Not sure where the issue is. Can anyone please help? 
Thanks in advance.

**Cron Job looks like :**

```
PYTHONPATH =/cs/../../thirdparty/python/2.6/bin/python
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
00 00 * * 2,3,4,5,6  /abc/logs/env/pqr/hvi/calculate_latency.sh  > /var/tmp/hvi_latency.log 2>&1
```

**Shell script looks like:**

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
cd /abc/logs/env/pqr/hvi/
NOW=$(date +"%F")
FILE="hvi-latency-$NOW.log"
zgrep "Received message:" $(date -d '-2 day' '+%Y%m%d')*.hvi.data.log.gz $(date -d'yesterday' +%Y%m%d)/*.data.* | cut -d' ' -f1,2,20,21,22 | sed 's/2016.*gz://' | sed 's/ /|/2'  > $FILE
chmod 777 $FILE
python /abc/logs/env/pqr/hvi/HVI_Delay_analyizer_BY_HOUR_usingDatetime.py $FILE /abc/logs/env/pqr/hvi/
chmod 777 HVI_MaxDelayPerHOUR.log
cut -d "|" -f2 HVI_MaxDelayPerHOUR.log >HVI_MaxDelay.log
chmod 777 HVI_MaxDelay.log
tail -n +2 HVI_MaxDelay.log > HVI_Latency.log
chmod 777 HVI_Latency.log
cat HVI_Latency.log > HVI_Latency.txt
chmod 777 HVI_Latency.txt
mail -s "DR Latency values for HVI feeder on date:$NOW" sajida.sayyad@gmail.com < HVI_Latency.txt
```

**python script looks like:**

```
import os
import sys
import time
import math
import re
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

def get_timestamp():
import datetime
n = datetime.datetime.now()
# print n gives : 2016-03-25 04:08:43.123162
result = '{0:04}-{1:02}-{2:02}_{3:02}{4:02}{5:02}'.format(n.year,n.month,n.day,n.hour,n.minute,n.second)
# print result gives :2016-03-25_040843
return result
```

**Error message is:**

```
[..... tmp]$ tail -100 hvi_latency.log 
2016-03-25 05:31:43.806450
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/abc/logs/env/pqr/hvi/HVI_Delay_analyizer_BY_HOUR_usingDatetime.py", line 119, in ?
START_TIME = get_timestamp()   
File "/abc/logs/env/pqr/hvi/HVI_Delay_analyizer_BY_HOUR_usingDatetime.py", line 18, in get_timestamp
result = '{0:04}-{1:02}-{2:02}_{3:02}{4:02}{5:02}'.format(n.year,n.month,n.day,n.hour,n.minute,n.second)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'format'
```

Comment: Put `somelocation/../thirdparty/python/2.6/bin` on the left-hand side of PATH - NEVER use relative path names in a cron job, always use absolute paths.

Comment: what do you mean when you say put ../../bin to left-hand side of PATH?

Comment: I changed the path to be :PATH=/xyz/def/thirdparty/python/2.6/bin/python:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin . Still getting the same error mentioned above.

Comment: Put a `which python` into shell script just before the call. Put a `print dir('')` just before the failing statement. Start python in your console and type `''.format`. What do you get? And I see a suspicious blank before the `=` of  `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: OK, then don't explicitly call `python` in your cron script, put the correct `#!` line on the first line of your python script and make sure its location is in PATH.  Then just call it.

Comment: 1). Your Python code is not indented correctly, but I guess that might just be a copy & paste error. 2). You don't need most of those `import`s: you only need `import datetime`, and it should be at the start of the script, _not_ inside the function definition. 3). As cdarke said, it may help if you have a correct `#!` line at the very top of your Python script.

Comment: @cdarke : I put #!/usr/bin/env python as a first line in my python script but it doesn't help. Also when I replace .format with 'result = datetime.strptime(n,"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S")' , it now errors out saying**strong'AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'**
'

Comment: @ Harald : The output of which python is /cs/zef/thirdparty/python/2.6/bin/python. The output of printdir('') is huge & I am not able to put it here. Let me know what do I check in that output?

Comment: @ PM 2Ring : If there isan issue with the script, how does it run fine when I execute the .sh manually on the location, why does it error out when cronjob triggers it? Also the python script is pretty big so I have other imports. The part I sent errors out.

Comment: @ Harald :['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getnewargs__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_formatter_field_name_split', '_formatter_parser', 'capitalize', 'center', 'count', 'decode', 'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs','find', 'format', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'join'

Comment: Don't use `#⁄usr/bin/env`, that will just get the same python as relying on `$PATH`, use the full python path after the `#!`.  I know lots of people say to use `env`, but that gives exactly these issues (and others).

Comment: @Cdarke: I used #!/cs/zef/thirdparty/python/2.6/bin/python as my shebang in python script. Also had this in my PATH in cronjob, but it dint work still :( . Also as per what I know we give shebang in the python script if its going to be a standalone executable script (i.e we want to execute it as ./xyz.py). This python I am trying to invoke is something like : 'python xyz.py input output'

Comment: This shows that strings do have a `format` attribute inthis context, which makes the error message extremely mysterious, even more so together with the claim that it only fails as cron job.

Comment: I finally got it working. I did a 'pydoc datetime' on the unix box at the above mentioned path and it gave me PYTHONPATH under the name 'FILE' which i assigned to PYTHONPATH in my cronjob. Guess it was not finding the exact module location & so was complaining about '.format' . Now it works fine. Python script gets called and the output file is generated.